# Are there any downsides to using data attribute to edit content with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am developing a simple web app and I need to update the displayed data after certain events or conditions. This data is scattered in many different places and within completely separate markup structures.
I have used classes in the past but found some dangerous cases when using classes to edit data has come to bite me (especially as we are using OOCSS and there are many classes we want to change and should not be bound to js data or behaviour). The solution below should be buletproof in this respect but as I have never seen it used before I fear I may be missing something.
Is there any downside to a solution like the following?

Example code below - using jQuery

The follow may be bound to a specific data-change event:

```
$('.data[data-type=user_data]').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.data[data-type=user_name]').html($.user.userName)
    .end().find('.data[data-type=user_location]').html($.user.userLocation)
    .end().find('.data[data-type=incident_date]').html($.user.incidentDate)
    .end().find('.data[data-type=incident_cost]').html($.user.incidentCost)
    .end().find('.data[data-type=user_hair_color]').html($.user.hairColor);

      //more data will be added here ...
```

});

Markup will be this in some places:

```
<div class="data incident_result bubbled_box" data-type="user_data">
<h3>Some heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Username:       <span class="data highlight name" data-type="user_name">Igor Wassel</span></li>
    <li>User location:  <span class="data" data-type="user_location">Estonia</span></li>
    <li>Provider:       <span class="data" data-type="incident_date">21/08/11</span></li>
</ul>
```

Other places the markup will include the other data but within a completely different html structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any downsides to using data attribute to edit content with
>   javascript?

No, unless you write to these attributes and read them back with JavaScript. As too many people do, unfortunately. DOM isn't the place to store your JavaScript state.

Otherwise, it's perfectly OK to send data from server to client side via `data`-attributes. To stay completely failsafe append some common prefix to all your `data`-attributes.

Only I doubt it's performant to *select* elements by attribute value. Methods like `getElementsByName` are optimized for the task.

One could, at least, expand internal jQuery `find`-loops to iterate over all elements and automatically retrieve their values.

```
$('.data[data-type=user_data] *').each(function (el) {
    el = $(el);
    type = el.data('type');
    if (type) {
        el.html($.user[type.toCamelCase()]);
    }
});

String.prototype.toCamelCase = function () { /* implement me */ };
```

And don't forget the HTML5 doctype declaration.

Comment: why do you say it's not good too store JS state in data attributes?

Comment: @garek007: It's not good doing lots of operations on elements, these are expensive. Also, html should be view, not model. Since ES6 you can use a Map object like hashtable and use the element as key, very cheap ;)

Comment: @OnnovanderZee can you link to documentation on this Map object?

Comment: @garek007: you asked for a documentation link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map . Example:  
    const myElm = document.querySelector('#myElm');
    const myData = {mine: true}
    const myMap = new Map();
    myMap.set(myElm, myData);
    myMap.get(myElm) // => {mine: true};